# Why app crashes with [NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:]?

Tags: swift, uiimageview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, prepareforreuse

The app sometimes crashes with `[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:]`, the selector being `[UIImageView setImage:]`.

[image]

I captured it by setting an exception breakpoint and the crash happens when setting an `UIImageView.image` in `prepareForReuse` of a `UICollectionViewCell`:

```
class MyCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    var coverImageView = UIImageView()

    ...

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()

        coverImageView.image = nil
    }
}
```

The `prepareForReuse` is called then the cell is instantiated:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = myCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "myReuseID", for: indexPath) as! MyCell
    ...
}
```

Why is that happening?

Also I cannot load the quick look data view for the `UIImageView` so maybe the object has been released?

[image]

The error messages in console are:

```
2017-01-21 15:56:19.653 MyApp[4873:20387361] -[__NSMallocBlock__ size]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x608000880aa0
2017-01-21 15:56:37.697 MyApp[4873:20387361] invalid mode 'kCFRunLoopCommonModes' provided to CFRunLoopRunSpecific - break on _CFRunLoopError_RunCalledWithInvalidMode to debug. This message will only appear once per execution.

2017-01-21 15:56:38.847 MyApp[4873:20617657] [Optimizely Logging]: Successfully saved data file to disk. Code revision is 229
2017-01-21 15:56:42.723 MyApp[4873:20387361] [Optimizely Logging]: (ERROR) NSInvalidArgumentException: Stack Trace:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f587d4b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010ef6121e objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f5f7f04 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f50d005 ___forwarding___ + 1013
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f50cb88 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   UIKit                               0x000000010ba5e20f -[UIImageView _updateImageViewForOldImage:newImage:] + 297
    6   UIKit                               0x000000010ba59950 -[UIImageView setImage:] + 391
    7   MyApp                              0x000000010945e0d8 _TFC6MyApp23MyCell15prepareForReusefT_T_ + 136
    8   MyApp                              0x000000010945e112 _TToFC6MyApp23MyCell15prepareForReusefT_T_ + 34
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010c19aed1 -[UICollectionView _dequeueReusableViewOfKind:withIdentifier:forIndexPath:viewCategory:] + 773
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010c19b8ea -[UICollectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:] + 169
    11  MyApp                              0x00000001095bdee2 _TFC6MyApp23MyViewController14collectionViewfTCSo16UICollectionView13cellForItemAtV10Foundation9IndexPath_CSo20UICollectionViewCell + 594
    12  MyApp                              0x00000001095be747 _TToFC6MyApp23MyViewController14collectionViewfTCSo16UICollectionView13cellForItemAtV10Foundation9IndexPath_CSo20UICollectionViewCell + 87
    13  UIKit                               0x000000010c18675f -[UICollectionView _createPreparedCellForItemAtIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes:isFocused:notify:] + 467
    14  UIKit                               0x000000010c186586 -[UICollectionView _createPreparedCellForItemAtIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes:] + 35
    15  UIKit                               0x000000010c18ba5e -[UICollectionView _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 4803
    16  UIKit                               0x000000010c191725 -[UICollectionView layoutSubviews] + 313
    17  UIKit                               0x000000010b90dab8 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1237
    18  QuartzCore                          0x000000010d558bf8 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 146
    19  QuartzCore                          0x000000010d54c440 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 366
    20  QuartzCore                          0x000000010d54c2be _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
    21  QuartzCore                          0x000000010d4da318 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 280
    22  QuartzCore                          0x000000010d5073ff _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 475
    23  QuartzCore                          0x000000010d507d6f _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 113
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f52c267 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f52c1d7 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 391
    26  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f510f8e __CFRunLoopRun + 1198
    27  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f510884 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
    28  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000112b77a6f GSEventRunModal + 161
    29  UIKit                               0x000000010b848c68 UIApplicationMain + 159
    30  MyApp                              0x00000001092f5a7f main + 111
    31  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001115b568d start + 1
)
2017-01-21 15:56:42.725 MyApp[4873:20387361] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSMallocBlock__ size]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x608000880aa0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f587d4b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010ef6121e objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f5f7f04 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f50d005 ___forwarding___ + 1013
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f50cb88 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   UIKit                               0x000000010ba5e20f -[UIImageView _updateImageViewForOldImage:newImage:] + 297
    6   UIKit                               0x000000010ba59950 -[UIImageView setImage:] + 391
    7   MyApp                              0x000000010945e0d8 _TFC6MyApp23MyCell15prepareForReusefT_T_ + 136
    8   MyApp                              0x000000010945e112 _TToFC6MyApp23MyCell15prepareForReusefT_T_ + 34
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010c19aed1 -[UICollectionView _dequeueReusableViewOfKind:withIdentifier:forIndexPath:viewCategory:] + 773
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010c19b8ea -[UICollectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:] + 169
    11  MyApp                              0x00000001095bdee2 _TFC6MyApp23MyViewController14collectionViewfTCSo16UICollectionView13cellForItemAtV10Foundation9IndexPath_CSo20UICollectionViewCell + 594
    12  MyApp                              0x00000001095be747 _TToFC6MyApp23MyViewController14collectionViewfTCSo16UICollectionView13cellForItemAtV10Foundation9IndexPath_CSo20UICollectionViewCell + 87
    13  UIKit                               0x000000010c18675f -[UICollectionView _createPreparedCellForItemAtIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes:isFocused:notify:] + 467
    14  UIKit                               0x000000010c186586 -[UICollectionView _createPreparedCellForItemAtIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes:] + 35
    15  UIKit                               0x000000010c18ba5e -[UICollectionView _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 4803
    16  UIKit                               0x000000010c191725 -[UICollectionView layoutSubviews] + 313
    17  UIKit                               0x000000010b90dab8 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1237
    18  QuartzCore                          0x000000010d558bf8 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 146
    19  QuartzCore                          0x000000010d54c440 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 366
    20  QuartzCore                          0x000000010d54c2be _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
    21  QuartzCore                          0x000000010d4da318 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 280
    22  QuartzCore                          0x000000010d5073ff _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 475
    23  QuartzCore                          0x000000010d507d6f _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 113
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f52c267 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f52c1d7 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 391
    26  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f510f8e __CFRunLoopRun + 1198
    27  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f510884 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
    28  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000112b77a6f GSEventRunModal + 161
    29  UIKit                               0x000000010b848c68 UIApplicationMain + 159
    30  MyApp                              0x00000001092f5a7f main + 111
    31  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001115b568d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: Maybe there is a different class assigned to that variable from Xib?

Comment: In your crash log there are missing steps between 0 and 4. Could you expand that, too?

Comment: @Sulthan I cannot expand it, it's not a crash log but the Debug Navigator in Xcoce. Also I don't think there are any steps 1-3, because the `setImage` is the selector where it seems to crash.

Comment: @Sulthan I am not using a Xib, the `UICollectionView` and `UICollecitonViewCell` are created in code.

Comment: Unselect the filters in the bottom of the debug navigator.

Comment: @Sulthan Allright, updated the image.

Comment: Note that you are still missing the error message, let the program continue and also please add the error message that will be written to your log.
This kind of of problems is usually caused by bad classes assigned to variables, badly written categories or subclasses or by method swizzling. That shouldn't be possible in Swift, only in Obj-C...

Comment: @Sulthan Ok, I posted the crash log.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you are not calling the designated initializer of `UIImageView`, therefore its `image` property is not properly initialized and trying to assign to it crashes the app:

> -[**NSMallocBlock** size]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x608000880aa0

The method tries to call the `size` method on the old image but the old image was set to some random memory address.

To fix it, initialize `UIImageView` properly using the designated initializer:

```
var coverImageView = UIImageView(image: nil)
```

Comment: That makes sense, I will try that. However, why is there the public initializer `UIImageView(void)` at all then? Shouldn't it be private if it causes a crash like this?

Comment: @Manuel It's inherited from `NSObject` (and `UIView`). In Objective-C the inheritance of initializers is not so simple as in Swift.

Comment: I see, and how do you interpret that it only crashes sometimes?

Comment: Changed the initializers of `UIImageView()` to `UIImageView(image: nil)` and `UIView()` to `UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)` but crash is still happening.